# Docker - Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306` with Prisma service

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, nestjs, prisma

I am running a nestjs project through docker which connects to redis and mysql
I am facing connection with with docker mysql and prisma service and also with redis
I have gone through lot of links but no luck.

Here is my code:
Dockerfile

```
    # ******** DEVELOPMENT ********
FROM node:14 AS development

RUN npm install --global pnpm

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml prisma ./

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --strict-peer-dependencies --reporter append-only --unsafe-perm

COPY . .

RUN pnpm build
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  main:
    container_name: nestproject
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    command: pnpm start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
   

  mysql:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - nestproject-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb

  redis:
    image: 'redis:5.0'
    volumes:
      - /data
    ports:
      - '6379'
    networks:
      - redis


networks:
  nestproject:
  redis:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  nestproject-mysql-data:
```

This is how I am connecting through my prisma client

```
const { url } = this.configService.get('database');

this.write_client = new PrismaClient({ datasources: { db: { url: url } } });

//url="mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/mydb"
```

The error which I get for Redis

```
{"name":"NestProject - RedisService","hostname":"1b080bc9c160","pid":36,"level":50,"err":{"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379","name":"Error","stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)\n    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)","code":"ECONNREFUSED"},"msg":"Redis Client Error","time":"2022-06-04T12:19:34.854Z","v":0}
```

The error which I get for mysql

```
{"name":"NestProject - ExceptionHandler","hostname":"1b080bc9c160","pid":36,"level":50,"msg":"Error: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`\n\nPlease make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`3306`.\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@3.8.0_prisma@3.8.0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:36270:21","time":"2022-06-04T12:19:34.868Z","v":0}
```

I don't understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I got it.

The problem was with the mysql url which I was using to connect.

The correct format

```
url="mysql://username:password@mysql:3306/database_name"
```

We have to use mysql instead of localhost since my service name is mysql

And regarding the redis issue I got the hint from @alex067 and I removed the

```
redis:
    driver: bridge
```

Thanks alex067

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

You're not exposing any ports for your mysql docker container.

As for your redis issue, you're creating a new bridged network called "redis." Bridged networks allow containers within the same network, to communicate.

Your main service is not part of this bridged network, thus the connection is being refused.

Comment: I have already tried with the ports of 3306, even then it does not work.

Also this is from the logs when the application is starting

     2022-06-04T13:37:59.302469Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
nestjsproject-mysql-1  | 

2022-06-04T13:37:59.304565Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Comment: Your docker compose clearly shows that port 3306 is not being opened.